# Cassandra on Windows: Fatal configuration error

Tags: configuration, cassandra

We installed Cassandra 2.0.6 in Windows 7 with JRE 7 and we updated the cassandra.yaml file as shown:

data_file_directories: D:\cassandra_data\data 
commitlog_directory: D:\cassandra_data\commitlog 
saved_caches_directory: D:\cassandra_data\saved_caches

When we are trying to start cassandra server (D:\cassabdra\bin\cassandra.bat) we are getting following error

**Starting Cassandra Server

 INFO 13:19:39,272 Logging initialized

 INFO 13:19:39,299 Loading settings from file:/D:/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

ERROR 13:19:39,540 Fatal configuration error**
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:111)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:153)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:471)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:560)
Caused by: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=data_file_directories for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@1cb839f; No single argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;
 in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    **cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use forward slashes (`/`), even on Windows:

In you case, it would be:

```
data_file_directories: 
    - "D:/cassandra_data/data" 
commitlog_directory: "D:/cassandra_data/commitlog" 
saved_caches_directory: "D:/cassandra_data/saved_caches"
```

Comment: Thank you jorgebg your solution is working perfectly